# Can phenol be detected with a ceric ammonium nitrate test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, phenols

Today, I came across a question which asked name three  reagents can be used for identification of phenol. The answer given was:

> 1. Neutral $\ce{FeCl3}$
> 2. $\ce{ NaNO2 +HCl}$
> 3. $\ce {(NH4)2[Ce(NO3)6]}$.

I understand (1) and (2), but I am doubtful about [CAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceric_ammonium_nitrate) test (3). As far as I have studied in various books, it is used for testing presence of alcohol, and **phenol is not alcohol**.

Can phenol be detected with a ceric ammonium nitrate test?

Answer (score 12):

With unsubstituted phenol ($\ce{PhOH}$) dark-brown precipitation is formed:

$$\ce{(NH4)2[Ce(NO3)6] + 2 PhOH -> [Ce(NO3)4(PhOH)2] + 2 NH4NO3}$$

Other phenols should produce wine-red solution as expected [1, p. 478]. Also, this and other phenol tests are discussed in [2].

1. Pavia, D. L. A small-scale approach to organic laboratory techniques, 3rd Ed.; Brooks/Cole, Cengage Learning: Belmont, CA, **2011**. ISBN 978-1-4390-4932-7.
2. Atul, S. The Pearson Guide to Objective Chemistry for the AIEEE; Pearson Education India, 2010. ISBN 978-81-317-3381-3.

Comment: Could you please give some examples of the "other phenols"? Would phluoroglucinol work? Or are only monohydroxy derivatives are acceptable?

Answer (score 7):

I have mentioned CAN test of alcohol and phenol in a [previous answer of mine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/reactions-of-phloroglucinol/50847#50847), so I am going to directly quote that:

> Genereally, CAN test is done for alcohols which give pink or red
>   colour. **But for phenols and phenolic compounds, it gives brown or
>   black color. So, this test helps to differentiate phenols from
>   alcohols**.

Unfortunately, the source link is broken. :(