# Can 1,3,5-trihydroxybenzene perform haloform reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

As far as I know it's not possible for 1,3,5-trihydroxybenzene to give the haloform reaction.

The prerequisites(that I know) for the haloform reaction are:

Only those organic compounds which can be converted to a methyl ketone or acetaldehyde by means of oxidation (by $\ce{NaOX}$ ($\ce{NaOH + X2}$) type agents which are present in the reaction mixture) give this reaction. And obviously a methyl ketone or acetaldehyde would give this reaction too.

So the problem is I don't see how  1,3,5-trihydroxybenzene meet those prerequisites. Is there any way out because in a recent practice test I came to know that **1,3,5-trihydroxybenzene does give the haloform reaction**.

Comment: Phloroglucinol(1,3,5 trihydroxybenzene) will not give haloform reaction. See this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/reactions-of-phloroglucinol

Comment: Did they give you the reason or even a hint as to why it gives the haloform reaction?

Comment: No hints were mentioned in the answer key.

Comment: Then that's probably the wrong answer. Although you may surely wish to keep this question open for a while, just in case someone has more detailed views.

Comment: There are two things here: 1) undergo actual **haloform** reaction 2) react,  when tested  for methyl ketone group, with iodine and sodium hydroxide mixture. First is impossible - no way you'll get haloform, second very probable.

Comment: @Mithoron alright...I couldn't get the second one /:

Comment: Actually it does give iodoform test. Its tautomer which is cyclohex-1,3,5-trione exists in quite a good amount in the solution which is why it gives the rest.

Comment: @FreakyChemist sounds great...I'd be grateful to you if you can show the mechanism because I still have a doubt as the keto form would not possess an independent methyl group as in acetaldehyde which is required for the reaction...

Comment: Could it be that instead of the usual -CX3 which is usually the leaving group in haloform reaction due to resonance stability and high -I of halogen, instead this time CX2 could form and with 2 Keto groups around it,they can provide high -I effect, resulting in favour of bond breaking and then the corresponding carbanion could be stabilised by the -I and -M effect of 2 Halogen and one double bonded Oxygen. Am I right @FreakyLearner. Or can anyone else........ kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It can undergo tautomerism which causes it to have active methylene grp which undergo haloform test